# Create custom jquery validation rule based on custom localized error message asp core 3.1

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-core

***Notes:***

1. I am using Shared resource to localize error messages and it works for all .net annotation attributes
2. I injected the dataannotation service to the startup class to accept the shared resource localization

Here is my code for reviewing

```
public string PageName { get; set; }    //For custom validation purposes
[Display(Name = "Name")]
[RequiredIf("PageName", "Contacts", ErrorMessage = "This field is required")]
public string PageName { get; set; }


public class RequiredIfAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientModelValidator
{
    private String PropertyName { get; set; }
    private Object DesiredValue { get; set; }
    private readonly RequiredAttribute _innerAttribute;
    public RequiredIfAttribute(String propertyName, Object desiredvalue)
    {
        PropertyName = propertyName;
        DesiredValue = desiredvalue;
        _innerAttribute = new RequiredAttribute();
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext context)
    {

        var dependentValue = context.ObjectInstance.GetType().GetProperty(PropertyName).GetValue(context.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (dependentValue != null && dependentValue.ToString() == DesiredValue.ToString())
        //if (dependentValue == null || dependentValue.ToString() != DesiredValue.ToString())
        {
            if (!_innerAttribute.IsValid(value))
            {
                // if validation result is wrong
                return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        // if validation result is correct
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }


    public void AddValidation(ClientModelValidationContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val", "true");
        context.Attributes.Add("data-val-requiredIf", ErrorMessage);  //Here i need to get the localized message
        context.Attributes.Add("data-seed-property", PropertyName);
        context.Attributes.Add("data-desired-value", DesiredValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an demo. Create a form in *Index.cshtml* according to this model.

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post">
<div>
    <label>PageName</label>   
    <input asp-for="@Model.PageName" />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="login" id="submit" value="save">
</div>
```

Reference jquery.validate.min.js and set the rule.

```
@section Scripts {
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#loginForm").validate({
            rules:
            {
                PageName://Locate the name value of the element attribute
                {
                    required: true,
                    minlength: 2,
                    maxlength: 10
                }
            },
            messages:
            {//Define rule prompt message
                PageName:
                {
                    required: "Le nom d'utilisateur ne peut pas être vide",
                    minlength: "Pas moins de 2",
                    maxlength: "Pas plus de 10 chiffres"
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
}
```

This property `message` defines the error message.

[image]